# Did Captain Picard suffer any permanent effects from The Inner Light?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Did Picard suffer any permanent problems from his time in [The Inner Light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inner_Light_%28Star_Trek%3a_The_Next_Generation%29)? I don't remember it ever being referred to in a subsequent episode, even though it gave him several years of memories.

Were there any lasting effects? Or did the memories fade?

Comment: It was mentioned in a later episode, I don't remember which one. And he learned to play the flute; I presume he kept that.

Comment: Another excellent question would be to ask the same thing about Chain of Command ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The flute was seen in a later episode titled "[Lessons](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/lessons)", where he shares his love for playing it with a woman he falls in love with.

The dialogue in the show indicate that the memories are very real and very important to him. He indicated that the memories are as much a part of him as any "real" memory, but there were never any lingering physical effects.

Comment: According to Memory Alpha, the [Ressikan flute](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ressikan_flute) is also seen in Nemesis.  I can't particularly recall this for myself though, so it may have just been a background prop there.

Comment: There was going to be a scene in Nemesis in which he played or held the flute, but it was deleted, IIRC.

Comment: There was another short scene at the beginning of "A Fistful of Datas" where he tries to make a recording with the flute. http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/A_Fistful_of_Datas_%28episode%29

Answer (score 22):

On [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Inner_Light_%28episode%29), Ronald D. Moore; Senior Writer and Producer of the episode is quoted as saying:

> "I've always felt that the experience in "Inner Light" would've been
>   the most profound experience in Picard's life and changed him
>   irrevocably. However, that wasn't our intention when we were creating
>   the episode. We were after a good hour of TV, and the larger
>   implications of how this would really screw somebody up didn't hit
>   home with us until later (that's sometimes a danger in TV – you're so
>   focused on just getting the show produced every week that sometimes
>   you suffer from the "can't see the forest for the trees" syndrome). **We
>   never intended the show to completely upend his character and force a
>   radical change in the series, so we contented ourselves with a single
>   follow-up in "Lessons"."**

Comment: Awesome quote. This specifically addresses the question and provides a canon answer. You have my +1

Answer (score 6):

His attitude towards children *markedly* changes.

As recently as the episode *Disaster* (s5e05), Picard expresses visible discomfort about vamping for a few hours with young children. After making a new life for himself and raising children with his wife in *The Inner Light* (s5e25) there isn't a whole lot of interaction between Picard and children (not counting Rascals, sigh) -- but in the movie Star Trek: Generations, we find that his first, ideal imaginary paradise is Thanksgiving dinner, surrounded by children (his own, as well as recently departed Rene) and family.

If one were to roll tape back to 1st and 2nd season Picard, one would surmise that naught but Earl Grey tea and archeology books await him in the Nexus. There have been few other potential catalysts for this change besides his experience with the Ressikan probe.

Comment: Also, the death of his nephew and brother and some sense of mantaining the family line